# access the out put from corr.test() in R

Tags: r

I want to access the individual tables generated by the command `corr.test()` in R.  I have a data frame containing 8 rows and 18 column.  After running `corr.test(data.frame)` it generated the out put I want but can't access the tables individually.  Any solution?

```
corr.test(JK[2:18])
JK2<-(corr.test(JK[2:18]))
JK2
```

Prasenjit

Comment: Which package are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuiming you're referring to the function in the `psych` package, you can simply access the tables as items in a list

```
require(psych)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(sample(8*18), 8, 18))
out <- corr.test(dat[2:18])
```

You can inspect the structure of the object by

```
str(out)
```

and can access the resulting eight tables using list indexing:

```
out[[1]] # Correlation matrix 
out[[2]] # Sample Size
out[[3]] # Probability values
# and so on
```